# RecyclerView doesn't inflate, rather updates the same view?

Tags: java, android, realm, android-recyclerview

I have an activity to implement a to-do list, containing a recyclerview with each item being a checkbox and textview, and each task is added from an edittext.
It stores data using Realm.io. The behaviour that I keep getting is that the single element in the recyclerview merely get updated, and not inflated! Please help.

TasksActivity -

```
public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView courseTitle;
    RecyclerView TaskList;
    EditText addTask;
    Button addButton;

    String transName; //Transferred Course name from MainActivity


    TaskAdapter TA;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        courseTitle = findViewById(R.id.CourseName);
        TaskList = findViewById(R.id.TaskListRV);
        TaskList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));


        addTask = findViewById(R.id.InputTask);
        addButton = findViewById(R.id.AddTaskButton);

        //Course name is the obtained from the previous acivity.

        transName =getIntent().getExtras().getString("CourseName");
        courseTitle.setText(transName);

        TA = new TaskAdapter(transName);
        TaskList.setAdapter(TA);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String task = addTask.getText().toString();

        // Checking if the text is empty.

        boolean flag = false;
        for(int i = 0;i<task.length();i++)
        {
            if(task.charAt(i)!=' ')
                flag = true;
        }

        if(!flag || task.equals(""))
        {
            Toast emptyWarning = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Task cannot be Empty!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            emptyWarning.show();
        }
        else
        {
            addTask.setText("");
            TA.addNewTask(task);

        }
    }

}
```

TasksAdapter -

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder> implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<TaskModel>>
{

    private ArrayList<TaskModel> TaskList;
    private String course;
    private final Realm realm;



        public TaskAdapter(String course)
        {
            this.course = course;

            this.TaskList = new ArrayList<>();
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            loadTaskData();
        }

        void loadTaskData()
        {
            RealmResults<TaskModel> taskModelRealmResults = realm.where(TaskModel.class).equalTo("courseName",course).findAll();
            taskModelRealmResults.addChangeListener(this);

            for(TaskModel iTM : taskModelRealmResults)
            {
                TaskList.add(realm.copyFromRealm(iTM));
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task,parent,false);

            TaskViewHolder Tvh = new TaskViewHolder(view);
            return Tvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.populateTask(TaskList.get(position));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return TaskList.size();
        }

        public void addNewTask(String task)
        {
            TaskModel newTaskObj = new TaskModel(task,course,false);

            TaskList.add(newTaskObj);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.insertOrUpdate(newTaskObj);
            realm.commitTransaction();

        }


        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<TaskModel> taskModels) {

            taskModels = realm.where(TaskModel.class).equalTo("courseName",course).findAll();
            this.TaskList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(TaskModel iTM : taskModels)
            {
                this.TaskList.add(realm.copyFromRealm(iTM));
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

TaskViewHolder and TaskModel - (in case you might need them)

```
public class TaskModel extends RealmObject {

    String task;

    @PrimaryKey
    String courseName;

    boolean isDone;

    public TaskModel() {
        task = "";
        courseName = "";
        isDone = false;
    }

    public TaskModel(String task, String courseName, boolean isDone) {
        this.task = task;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }


    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        isDone = done;
    }
}

public class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    CheckBox isdone;
    TextView Taskname;


    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        isdone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TaskCheckBox);
        Taskname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TaskName);

    }

    void populateTask(final TaskModel T)
    {
        Taskname.setText(T.getTask());
        isdone.setChecked(T.isDone());

        isdone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                T.setDone(isdone.isChecked());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `merely get updated, and not inflated!` isn't it how the `RecyclerView` is designed to work? To reuse views instead of creating new?

Comment: I meant _update_ as in the same set of views get replaced with the next set of data. Only a  _single view_  is displayed at a time.

Comment: that is probably because that view's layout is large enough to cover whole RecyclerView.

Comment: Does `onChange` return the whole list? Or just the last item(s) that have changed?

Comment: `private ArrayList<TaskModel> TaskList;` and `TaskList.add(realm.copyFromRealm(iTM));` WHY??? What example shows this?  Because I know the [officials don't](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/gridViewExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmgridview/GridViewExampleActivity.java#L34-L67)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. I ended up using the standard `ReacyclerView.Adapter`.
The problem was with the usage of Realm's `insertOrUpdate` method, when the `@PrimaryKey` was `courseName` which thus caused it to indeed update the same object and not create a new one!
`insert()` should have been used.
Here is the insert task method -

```
  public void addNewTask(String task)
{
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i = 0;i<TaskList.size();i++)
    {
        if(task.equals(TaskList.get(i).getTask()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Task already exists!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        TaskModel newTaskObj = new TaskModel();
        newTaskObj.setTask(task);
        newTaskObj.setDone(false);
        newTaskObj.setCourseName(course);

        TaskList.add(newTaskObj);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.insert(newTaskObj);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } }
```

The entire project can be found here, do check it out - 
https://github.com/Hariram-R/ToDoList-App

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [Realm Android dapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), this adapter is taking care of updating your app UI. Don't need to implement OnChangeListener, your list will be automatically updated after insertion, deletion or edition

Use [findAllAsync](https://www.realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries) in order to not block the UI thread

```
OrderedRealmCollection<TaskModel> taskModels = realm.where(TaskModel.class).equalTo("courseName", course).findAllAsync();

public RealmAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<TaskModel> data) {
    super(data, true);
}
```

*EDIT:*

Also always do the process using **Async** method when it's possible. You can replace your **addNewTask** method by:

```
public void addNewTask(String task) {
     final TaskModel newTaskObj = new TaskModel(task, course, false);

     realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTaskObj);
        }
     });
}
```

Yous should have something like this:

**TasksActivity**

```
public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText addTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        String transName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CourseName");

        TextView courseTitle = findViewById(R.id.CourseName);
        courseTitle.setText(transName);

        addTask = findViewById(R.id.InputTask);

        findViewById(R.id.AddTaskButton).setOnClickListener(this);

        OrderedRealmCollection<TaskModel> taskModels = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(TaskModel.class).equalTo("courseName", transName).findAllAsync()
        TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, taskModels);

        RecyclerView taskList = findViewById(R.id.TaskListRV);
        taskList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        taskList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String task = addTask.getText().toString().trim();

        if (task.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast emptyWarning = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Task cannot be Empty!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            emptyWarning.show();
            return;
        }

        addTask.setText("");
        addNewTask(task);
    }

    private void addNewTask(String task) {
        final TaskModel newTaskObj = new TaskModel(task, course, false);
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTaskObj);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And **TaskAdapter**:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<TaskModel, TaskViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater

    public TaskAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<TaskModel> taskModels) {
        super(taskModels, true);

        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new TaskViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task , parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.populateTask(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this Adapter? I am using Realm 5.3.0 (newest) and yet this Adapter is not present. Is there another dependency that I have to add?

Comment: Just have to add this dependency: **implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.1'**

Comment: There a new version available for the adapter, the **3.0.0** => implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0'

Comment: Thank you for the much needed help. I'm getting the required behaviour for inflating the view, however the data disappears when I open the TasksActivity again. `copyToRealmOrUpdate` should work right?

Comment: `copyToRealmOrUpdate ` should update or create object, it will not remove your database.
Are you sure to not clear your realm database somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the data is not cleared anywhere else. I reckon there's an issue with `loadTaskData()` method probably, but Im not able to point out the issue. Thanks for the help anyway.